# Why we are getting exception when we enable the query-cache in hibernate.cfg.xml file by use hibernate 5.3.1.Final dependency?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-cache

**I created a small second level cache program by using 'hibernate 5.3.1.final' dependency.I used below dependencies to work with Second level cache.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**In this dependency  the 'EhcacheRegionFactory' package name was changed.so we need to use like below property in our 'hibernate.cfg.xml'file.**

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

**In hibernate 5.3 the second level cache is working fine but 'query-cache' is not working.i am getting below exception when iam enabling the query-cache in 'hibernate.cfg.xml'.**

```
->Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
->Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create 
   requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
->Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: On-the-fly creation of 
  JCache Cache objects is not supported 
  [org.hibernate.cache.spi.TimestampsRegion]
```

> How to solve this one?

**But The same program when i tried with hibernate 5.2.17 dependency the query cache working fine.**

Answer (score 1):

Use Hibernate ORM Hibernate Core » 5.3.4.Final dependencies it will work

Comment: It is comment quality answer

Comment: No it does not helps